# How to concatenate a list of data frames with different lengths?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames, with the same columns, but with a different number of rows in each data frame. How do I concatenate all the rows together into a single data frame?

```
require('jsonlite')

# Get the list of repos for each of these GitHub user
users <- c('hadley', 'schmidt4brains', 'fred')
urls <- lapply(users, function(user) paste0("https://api.github.com/users/", user, "/repos"))

# Fetch all the repos from all users.
# Now we have a list of 3 data frames: same columns, but different row counts
repo_list <- lapply(urls, fromJSON)
```

How do I combine all the rows from all the data frames into a single data frame?

`sapply(repo_list, identity)` combines all the rows, but the result is not a data frame, and it has lost all the column names.

Comment: you want `rbind()` or succintly `do.call(rbind,repo_list)`

Answer (score 2):

`repos <- rbind_pages(repo_list)` does the trick.

Of course, after searching StackOverflow for hours, trying twenty different failed approaches, and getting up the nerve for format a question that demonstrates my problem, I find my own answer 15 minutes after posting!

Comment: Nice. One of the peculiarities of your `repo_list` is that the `dataframe` list elements contain another nested `dataframe`...

Comment: Yep, @MauritsEvers, I'm dealing with pages of arbitrary JSON results from the `jsonlite` package. Like you said, those results can contain arbitrary nesting of other data frames. It was that nesting that made all the stock guidance of "just use do.call(rbind)" fall over. Oh well, it's working now, so ship it! :)

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively...

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(repo_list)
```

http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html